# modifying the title tag of an excellently ranked page vs creating an alternative page with a 301 redirect

Tags: seo, http-status-code-301

I've got a page whose title as "mysite.com - CAT STEVENS".

Google finds mysite easily (above the fold) if the search phrase is CAT STEVENS.
In other words, when the search phrase is CAT STEVENS, my page shows up above the fold.

**But, if someone were to search YUSUF ISLAM instead, my page does not show up at all.**

Which of the following 2 options below would you recommend to me so that when YUSUF ISLAM is searched, I can appear above the fold too?

1- Simply change the current title

from *"mysite.com - CAT STEVENS"*

to    *"mysite.com - CAT STEVENS / YUSUF ISLAM"*

and wait for Google to reindex the page. 
I'm afraid of this change, cause it may hurt the current excellent placement.

2- Or create a new page under my web site, whose title is

*mysite.com - YUSUF ISLAM*

and place a 301 redirect on that page to the first page "mysite.com - CAT STEVENS" page, the one with the excellent placement.

this option to me seems to be a better solution cause it does not touch the currently ranked page. At least, I'f safe for those who searched *CAT STEVENS*.

and with a 301 redirect, I don't get the google's wrath due to duplicate content violation.

What say you?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change the title yet. I would update the content to include the fact that they are the same person. And make it real content, not just add the name and walk away. Maybe tell when and how he changed his name, where in his career he was when he made the change. Quality content is always the most important element. 
Wait at least 3 weeks and see if you are getting traffic from that keyword. 
The additional page may water down your high ranking page since the content will have to be similar. So, I wouldn't add a page - it is the same person, so it makes sense that the content should be appended.